# Is it a bad idea to make coffee ground decomposable baskets when planting?

Tags: planting

I've noticed that all the plants I put coffee grounds on are huge about 2 months into the growing season, and was thinking that since those plants do so well I may want to use more of them on my father's day gifts.

This is what I will be planting for him:
3 strawberry plants (freebees for my zone)
5 sea buckthorn (1 male, 4 females)

Comment: Did you do a controlled planting with others not given coffee grounds?

Comment: I did tests from previous years, this year it has a lot of grounds, and topping some of the plants off with them.

Comment: Coffee grounds make the ground a bit more acidic and some plants like that, but not all plants will like it. Research your plants on which ones like more acidic soil. Coffee grounds also offer some other nutrient but I can't recall what it is.

Comment: the ground is also a PH sponge I've heard

Comment: Yes it is, that means that treatments don't last because the pH of the surrounding soil will soak the amendment. Using slow release pH emmendment like peat moss and coffee grounds keep the pH lower for longer until they've mostly decomposed. You still must refresh it though.

Comment: Blue berries are a very good example of low pH loving plants. Cranberries as well. Anything that grows naturally in acidic conditions like bogs and forest floors where the ground is more like compost than like dirt will do well in coffee grounds.